# DCIM directory path on Android - Return Value

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have requirement of getting DCIM directory path from Native code. I am using the following code snippet:

```
jclass envClass = env->FindClass("android/os/Environment");
char charParam[] = "Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM";
jstring jstrParam = env->NewStringUTF(charParam);
jmethodID getExtStorageDirectoryMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(envClass, "getExternalStoragePublicDirectory",  "(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/io/File;");
jobject extStorageFile = env->CallStaticObjectMethod(envClass, getExtStorageDirectoryMethod, jstrParam);
jclass fileClass = env->FindClass("java/io/File");
jmethodID getPathMethod = env->GetMethodID(fileClass, "getPath", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring extStoragePath = (jstring)env->CallObjectMethod(extStorageFile, getPathMethod);
const char* extStoragePathString = env->GetStringUTFChars(extStoragePath,NULL);

//use extStoragePathString
LOGI("DCIM_PATH ==================================== %s", extStoragePathString);
```

But result is always `[PATH_TO_SD_CARD]/Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM`. I checked this is couple of devices as well as on Emulator. I created DCIM directory on emulator. Path to SD Card is correct.

As a solution, I can always go ahead and search for DCIM directory on SD Card. Because anyway under DCIM, I have to search where are pics. But still, Why aren't I getting the path to DCIM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` is the qualified Java name of the [static String defined](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Environment.html#DIRECTORY_DCIM) in the `Environment` class for the DCIM folder. However, it's isn't the actual *value* of the String, which is just ["DCIM"](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r1/android/os/Environment.java#Environment.0DIRECTORY_DCIM):

```
public static String DIRECTORY_DCIM = "DCIM";
```

You need to pass the String value, not the Java name of the variable, so you can change your code like this:

```
char charParam[] = "DCIM";
```

Passing this value as a parameter is equivalent to calling:

```
Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM);
```

in Java, given that `Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM` is defined as "DCIM".

However, if you do not want to use a hard-coded value, you can look up the static field from the `Environment` class, like this:

```
jfieldID fieldId = env->GetStaticFieldID(envClass, "DIRECTORY_DCIM", "Ljava/lang/String;");
jstring jstrParam = (jstring)env->GetStaticObjectField(envClass, fieldId);
```